# Should I cut off roots that grow out from a pot's drain?

Tags: containers, roots, root-pruning

I have a Ficus lyrata whose roots have grown out of the 25cm pot's drain hole. They form a dish shape within the pot's dish. Is it wise to cut these roots so that the pot can sit level again, or is it a sign that I need a larger pot?

Comment: You needed a larger pot as soon as any roots emerged from the drain holes, not after they are making the pot unstable. Unless you destroy the pot by cutting it up, you may *have* to prune the roots now to get the plant out of it. In any case, it is better to prune any roots that you damage while "unpotting" the plant.

Comment: @alephzero - can you construct your comment as an answer - you  have the right of it, but unless you post it as an answer, it can't be voted on nor accepted...

Answer (score 1):

I have a 10 ft tall Lyrata in a 30 cm pot. It has some roots out the bottom and a few over the top rim and down to the saucer. I don't trim the roots and I am not moving it to a bigger pot as this one is already a hassle to move out in the spring and back inside in the fall. So I think you can do what you want.